# WebAudio not playing after stop(0)

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm writing something like a web-audio-editor, and I think I'm close to finishing the basics. I can play and stop an audiofile, but when I try to call the play method again it just won't work, even though the parameters havn't changed.

I'd be glad to see someone look into my problem as I cannot see why it doesn't work when similar code in other projects does. Unfortunately I cannot create a jsfiddle, because I would need to load an external mp3-file and it seems I'm not allowed to do that. But I have pasted the javascript [here](http://pastebin.com/PpRwDSkW) and the corresponding html file [here](http://pastebin.com/W3S2Geyd).

All you need is a server you can upload the files to and a mp3 on it. Alternately you could use [this link](http://blackminded.de/test/test.html), but I will delete the files eventually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't call `start()` on an `AudioBufferSourceNode` more than once. They're one-time-use only.

Really the only way to do this is to create a new `AudioBufferSourceNode` from the underlying `AudioBuffer` every time you need to start playback.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. What would be the fastest way to "copy" all the properties into a NEW AudioBufferSourceNode? Is there a reason why it has to be done like that? I can think of none that woul make real sense.

Comment: All you really need to do is say `var newSource = context.createBufferSource(); newSource.buffer = oldAudioBuffer;`. As to why it works this way... not really sure. I suspect it has to do with memory/performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also leave it running and simply disconnect it from the gain-node, and the oscillator would presumably just idly/silently produce a waveform.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating a new `AudioBufferSourceNode`, you can simply use the `playbackRate` like this:

`source.playbackRate.value = 0;` to pause.

`source.playbackRate.value = 1;` to play.